# canvas - how to select multi rectangle area on image?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
make_base();
init();


function make_base() {
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 800, 500);
  }
}

function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 800, 500);
  context.font = '12pt Calibri';
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillText(message, 25, 25);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function init() {

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    if(drag) {
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
        context.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
        draw();
    }
}

function draw() {
    context.lineWidth="1";
    context.strokeStyle = "blue";
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
```

Now I can draw multi rectangle on image using mouse.
However, it will be white?

How to draw a rectangle more like select a area?

Comment: _"how t draw multiples rectangle on image?"_ (with _"Now I can draw multi rectangle on image using mouse"_ in the question) vs. _"How to draw a rectangle more like select a area?"_ The title should introduce the problem and not a non-relevant fact

Comment: Thanks. I edit it.

Answer (score 14):

### Best practice.

#### Rendering

You should never render from mouse or other UI events as they are not synced to the display. This can result in unpleasant shearing and flickering and also cause needless rendering that may only be partially or not at all seen, chewing power and battery life for no reason.

If you are regularly updating elements in the DOM (not just canvas) use render loop called via `requestAnimationFrame`. This ensures you only present DOM content that can be seen.

#### Lost input

When getting mouse input that is intended to be dragged you should listen to the document's mouse events rather than the element's. This allows you to follow the dragged input when it moves of the element and page. If you do not do this the drag can get locked if the user drags of the element/page and releases the mouse button.

Both the other answers fail to handle this correctly.

#### Constants and style

Use constants (`const`) wherever possible. They are block scoped and help to reduce bugs (though this is arguable).

Get used to adding `"use strict";` top the top of your code, it will help you reduce and spot bugs early. Do not add `"use strict"` once you have completed the code unless you do full testing cycle as it will/may break what was once working code.

Though best practice do not define naming styles it does mean that you use a naming style consistently. If you choose snake case (`snake_case`) then use it throughout the code, if you choose camel case (`camelCase`) then only use that. You remember variable as the words, trying to remember which style you used for a variable will slow you down and can result in bugs.

```js
"use strict";
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const storedRects = [];
const baseImage = loadImage("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
var refresh = true;
const rect = (() => {
    var x1, y1, x2, y2;
    var show = false;
    function fix() {
        rect.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
        rect.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
        rect.w = Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2);
        rect.h = Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2);
    }
    function draw(ctx) { ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h) }
    const rect = {x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, h : 0,  draw};
    const API = {
        restart(point) {
            x2 = x1 = point.x;
            y2 = y1 = point.y;
            fix();
            show = true;
        },
        update(point) {
            x2 = point.x;
            y2 = point.y;
            fix();
            show = true;
        },
        toRect() {
            show = false;
            return Object.assign({}, rect);
        },
        draw(ctx) {
            if (show) { rect.draw(ctx) }
        },
        show : false,
    }
    return API;
})();

function loadImage(url) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = () => refresh = true;
    return image;
}

const mouse = {
    button : false,
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    down : false,
    up : false,
    element : null,
    event(e) {
        const m = mouse;
        m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
        m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
        const prevButton = m.button;
        m.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
        if (!prevButton && m.button) { m.down = true }
        if (prevButton && !m.button) { m.up = true }
    },
    start(element) {
        mouse.element = element;
        "down,up,move".split(",").forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouse.event));
    }
}

mouse.start(canvas);
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.width);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    storedRects.forEach(rect => rect.draw(ctx));
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    rect.draw(ctx);
}
function mainLoop() {
    if (refresh || mouse.down || mouse.up || mouse.button) {
        refresh = false;
        if (mouse.down) {
            mouse.down = false;
            rect.restart(mouse);
        } else if (mouse.button) {
            rect.update(mouse);
        } else if (mouse.up) {
            mouse.up = false;
            rect.update(mouse);
            storedRects.push(rect.toRect());
        }
        draw();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" title = "click and drag to add rectangles" style="border:1px solid #000000;cursor:crosshair"></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't understand why it has only 8 votes.

Answer (score 0):

**Heavily** inspired by @Blindman67's excellent answer, this solution accepts touch events as well as mouse events, which I required for my own use.

The idea of the API Object was maintained but called "RectangleMaker".

Animation frames are only requested on the move event.

I found it hard to follow the signature *mouse* object run through the *mainLoop* loop function so I pulled that apart into three functions: "start", "move" and "stop". Events are added individually for each event type.

There are a few extra bits:

The code is invoked via a constructor so as to allow many canvases on a page.

Rectangle can preloaded, rectangle can be returned.

```js
function AnnotateImage (canvas) {
  const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const rectangleMaker = new RectangleMaker(canvasContext);
  const mouseObj = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let dragAction = false;
  const img1 = new Image();
  img1.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  attachEvents(canvas);

  let rectangles = [];

  this.returnRectangles = () => {
    return rectangles;
  };

  this.loadRectangles = (rects) => {
    rectangles = rects;
    rectangleMaker.drawRectangles();
    return this;
  };

  function RectangleMaker (canvasContext) {
    let x1, y1, x2, y2;
    const finishedRectangle = { x: 0, y: 0, w: 0, h: 0 };

    function makeFinishedRectangle () {
      finishedRectangle.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
      finishedRectangle.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
      finishedRectangle.w = Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2);
      finishedRectangle.h = Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2);
    }

    this.setFirstPoint = (point) => {
      return setFirstPoint(point);
    };

    function setFirstPoint (point) {
      x2 = x1 = point.x;
      y2 = y1 = point.y;
      makeFinishedRectangle();
    }

    this.setSecondPoint = (point) => {
      return setSecondPoint(point);
    };

    function setSecondPoint (point) {
      x2 = point.x;
      y2 = point.y;
      makeFinishedRectangle();
    }

    this.saveLocal = () => {
      const rect = Object.assign({}, finishedRectangle);
      rectangles.push(rect);
    };

    this.getRectangleToSave = () => {
      return getRectangleToSave();
    };

    function getRectangleToSave () {
      return Object.assign({}, finishedRectangle);
    }

    this.drawRectangles = () => {
      return drawRectangles();
    };

    function drawRectangles () {
      if (rectangles && rectangles.length > 0) {
        rectangles.forEach((rectangle) => {
          canvasContext.strokeRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.w, rectangle.h);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function attachEvents (canvas) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      start(e);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
      start(e);
    });

    function start (e) {
      const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      mouseObj.x = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX : e.targetTouches[0].pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
      mouseObj.y = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY : e.targetTouches[0].pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
      rectangleMaker.setFirstPoint(mouseObj);
      dragAction = true;
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      move(e);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
      move(e);
    });

    function move (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (dragAction) {
        // const prior = rectangleMaker.getRectangleToSave();
        // canvasContext.strokeRect(prior.x, prior.y, prior.w, prior.h);
        const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseObj.x = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX : e.targetTouches[0].pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
        mouseObj.y = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY : e.targetTouches[0].pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
        rectangleMaker.setSecondPoint(mouseObj);
        const newRect = rectangleMaker.getRectangleToSave();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          canvasContext.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
          rectangleMaker.drawRectangles();
          canvasContext.strokeRect(newRect.x, newRect.y, newRect.w, newRect.h);
        });
      }
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
      stop(e);
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
      stop(e);
    });

    function stop (e) {
      dragAction = false;
      const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      mouseObj.x = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX : e.changedTouches[0].pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
      mouseObj.y = (e.type.includes('mouse')) ? e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY : e.changedTouches[0].pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
      rectangleMaker.setSecondPoint(mouseObj);
      rectangleMaker.saveLocal();
      rectangleMaker.drawRectangles();
    }
  }
}

/**
  * @description code to load the canvas and call the Annotate constructor
  */
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
loadImageFromlink(canvas).then(() => {
  const annotate = new AnnotateImage(canvas);
});

function loadImageFromlink (canvas) {
 const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     const img = new Image();
     img.src = canvas.dataset.src;
     img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
     img.onload = () => {
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       resolve('loaded');
    };
  });
  return promise;
}
```

```html
<canvas data-src="https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/dcd88fe5876fd549823feb35af14c0ae9f0885b6/c=0-25-492-303/local/-/media/Phoenix/None/2014/10/17/635491415661570024-garfi8.PNG?width=492&height=277&fit=crop&format=pjpg&auto=webp"></canvas>
```